# Disappearing list elements when re-sizing width of list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, list

I have a horizontal list and want to animate the width of the list to simulate a scroll closing.

Here's a Fiddle demonstrating the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/a5Tfu/1/

The problem is that when the width overlaps any but the first list element, the content of that list element vanishes completely rather than gradually disappears off of the edge of the list as the width lessens, like it does with the first list element.

What I'd like is the same effect as the re-sizing width has on the first element, but on all of the elements.

Here is the css:

```
#container {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 1000px;
    height: 400px;
}

#list {
    background: #f7f7f7;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 1660px;
    height: 400px;
}   
    #list li {
        width: 400px;
        height: 400px;
        list-style: none;
        float: left;
    }   

        #left {
            position: relative;
            float: left;
            width: 200px;
            height: 400px;
        }

        #right {
            position: relative;
            float: right;    
            width: 200px;
            height: 400px;
        }
```

html template:

```
<div id="container">
    <ul id="list">
        <li>
            <div id="left">
                <p></p>
            </div>
            <div id="right">
                <p></p>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div id="left">
                <p></p>
            </div>
            <div id="right">
                <p></p>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div id="left">
                <p></p>
            </div>
            <div id="right">
                <p></p>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div id="left">
                <p></p>
            </div>
            <div id="right">
                <p></p>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

js:

```
$(function(){

    $('#list').animate({width: '200px'}, 5000);

});
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Animate the container instead of the list. JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/F5rLB/

```
$('#container').animate({width: '100px'}, 5000);
```